# Replace dropdown list items using JQuery html method

Tags: jquery, listbox

I would like to know if updating the contents of a listbox by using the html method as follows is a correct approach:

```
<select id="myListbox">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="empty" value="Replace listbox HTML" />

$(function(){
    $('#empty').click(function(){
            $('#myListbox').html('<option value="a">Item A</option><option value="b" selected>Item B</option><option value="c">Item C</option>');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/carolinebeltran/nLqgy20b/

I have test this and it works on FF, Chrome, and IE.  Firebug does not report any errors but I just want to be sure that what I am doing is actually correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function will absolutely work for this, you could consider storing your options within an array and then manually emptying your `<select>` element via the [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function and manually appending each new `<option>` as seen below :

```
// Store your new options in an array
var newOptions = {'Item A': 'a','Item B': 'b', 'Item C': 'c'};
// Clear out your current options
$('#myListBox').empty();
// Add each new option to the element
$.each(newOptions, function(value,key) {
    // Create a new <option> appending the values and text and add it to the list
    $('#myListBox').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

**Don't Forget Selection When Replacing With `html()`**

Another thing to keep in mind when using the `html()` approach that the current index that is selected will still be persisted after the change is made, which you could take care of via the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function :

```
$('#empty').click(function(){
    // Update your HTML here
    $('#myListbox').html('...'); 
    // Remove your selection
    $('#myListbox :selected').prop('selected', false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am creating a large list of option tags (as in my example above) on the back-end.  I obtain the options via an AJAX response and use JQuery's html method to update the listbox.  It is very convenient for me this way and seemed to work just fine.  I appreciate your suggestions as well as confirming that it is OK for me to do it the way I did because I had not been able to find an example of others doing it that way.